# LWUIT Container capture event

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40, lwuit-container

I have a `Container`with so many `Labels` added inside it. When I try to capture the `pointerReleased` event in this `Container`, I have found some problems. The event only is captured when I released in the free area of the `Container`, no when I made the release over the `Labels`. Is there any way to encapsulate this event? I mean when I will do the realase over the main `Container`(instead I'm on a Label), the event must be launched.

Here you can take a look at my `Container`

[image: Container Image]

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the lead component feature added in LWUIT 1.5, it allows you to define a component that manages the entire hierarchy of container/component and all events for every component in the hierarchy are sent to it.

This adds another benefit of handling the style synchronization between all the different elements (e.g. if you use a button all components will become pressed together).

Comment: Ok, I will take a look on this. Thank you one more time @Shai

Answer (score 0):

I dont' find any cool solution, so finally I propagate the pointerReleased from the `Labels`to the `Container`.